# Configuring yum repo to install packages only from my company internal network

Tags: linux, centos, repository, yum

I am trying to configure my yum repo on my centos7 machine to install packages only from my internal repository. To do that, I have done following changes:

1. Moved all the current repo configurations to different location:

   sudo mv /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo ~/backup_yum_repos/
2. Create a new file `Mycompany-internals.repo` under /etc/yum.repos.d
3. Added following contents to it:

```
[Mycompany-internals]
name=Mycompany-internals
baseurl=http://linux-repo.my-company.com/abc-2021q2-sr/CentOS-$releasever-$basearch/RPMS.all/
baseurl=http://linux-repo.my-company.com/epel/abc-2021q2-sr/epel/epel
baseurl=http://linux-repo.my-company.com/epel/abc-2021q2-sr/epel/epel-debuginfo/
baseurl=http://linux-repo.my-company.com/epel/abc-2021q2-sr/epel/epel-source/
baseurl=https://linux-repo.my-company.com/utilities/avamar/CentOS$releasever/
baseurl=https://linux-repo.my-company.com/utilities/splunk/v8/
baseurl=http://linux-repo.my-company.com/utilities/perforce/perforce
baseurl=http://linux-repo.my-company.com/utilities/docker/docker/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Now, I expect a normal yum installation to work using my registry mentioned above.

But when I run `yum install docker` (for example), it fails with error:

```
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror, langpacks, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
My-company-internal                                                                                                              | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
My-Company-internal/primary_db                                                                                                   |  42 kB  00:00:00     
No package docker available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Have you set up a satellite or spacewalk server?

Comment: http://linux-repo.my-company.com/* these are existing repos that I can use to install packages. I dont have more idea about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using baseurl= statement multiple times which is bad, below is a quote from yum.conf man page:

```
              baseurl Must be a URL to the directory where the yum repository's `repodata' directory lives. Can be an http://, ftp://  or
              file:// URL. You can specify multiple URLs in one baseurl statement. The best way to do this is like this:
              [repositoryid]
              name=Some name for this repository
              baseurl=url://server1/path/to/repository/
                      url://server2/path/to/repository/
                      url://server3/path/to/repository/

              If  you  list  more than one baseurl= statement in a repository you will find yum will ignore the earlier ones and probably
              act bizarrely. Don't do this, you've been warned.
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version is your yum?, there is a bug where yum will recognize the first URL and ignore the rest, this has been fixed in version yum-3.4.3-159.el7.

Comment: I am using 3.4.3.

Comment: what is the output of the this command?,  rpm -qa yum

Comment: yum-3.4.3-163.el7.centos.noarch

Comment: I am very new to this yum and system admin world. So I doubt on myself that I must be missing some basic things or configuration.